# Why std::stack memory size is bigger than as usual in c++?

Tags: c++, gcc, memory-management, stack, libstdc++

This is the code for testing my question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int num;
    int Array[1];
    stack<int> Stack;

    cout << "Int size " << sizeof(num) <<endl; // Output: Int size 4
    cout << "Array size " << sizeof(num) <<endl; // Output: Array size 4
    cout << "Stack size " << sizeof(Stack) <<endl; // Output: Stack size 80
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to understand about memory space allocation. Normally int memory size is 4 bytes. But, when I initialize an `Stack` of int data-type in `std::stack` then the `Stack` size is 80 bytes.

Should it 4? Why is `std::stack` taking 80 bytes? Or what is actually inside of stack for being the size 80 bytes?

Comment: What compiler/standard library are you using?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili GNU GCC Compiler

Comment: `std::stack` is a class. The class object itself uses some memory.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Just i tested with class also. The class size is 1 byte. I think stack is containing something for taking 80 bytes. Question is here what actually inside in stack for taking 80 bytes?

Comment: Comparison of space used by some common collections: https://ideone.com/f7sfcK

Answer (score 5):

`sizeof` gets the static size of the object/type. `stack` dynamically allocates memory for its elements. So, there is no correlation between size of the elements and size of `stack` in general. So, why is it 80 bytes? This is highly implementation specific. Size of stack is usually the same as the underlying container. By default, the underlying container is a `std::deque`, so that's where we must have a look. I checked libstdc++ specifically, and it seems to have 1 pointer, 1 size_t for size and 2 iterators like so:

```cpp
struct _Deque_impl_data
{
    _Map_pointer _M_map;
    size_t _M_map_size;
    iterator _M_start;
    iterator _M_finish;
    //...
```

(`std::deque` derives from `_Deque_base` which has a single member of type `_Deque_impl_data`)

Pointer and integer are 8 bytes, the iterators are 32 bytes. This adds up to 80 bytes. I didn't further investigate, but since `deque` is a more complex structure, it's only natural that it needs some memory for its own book-keeping.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe confusing `sizeof(Stack)` with `Stack.size()` here. The `sizeof` operator returns the total size of the *class object*, which, in the case of `std::stack` includes (of necessity) a number of internal data and control variables (padding the size out to, in your case, 80 bytes). However, a call to `Stack.size()` will return the *number of items* currently on the stack.

These 'internal variables' will include such things as a pointer to the allocated memory (likely 8 bytes), a value recording the current element count (also likely to be 8 bytes) and a number of other pointers and counters, to aid in manipulation of the stack and optimization of access to the contained data, such as the current *capacity* of the allocated space, etc.

The following modified code shows the difference:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int num;
    int Array[1];
    stack<int> Stack;

    cout << "Int size " << sizeof(num) << endl;     // Int size 4
    cout << "Array size " << sizeof(Array) << endl; // Array size 4 (1 "int" element)
    cout << "Stack size " << sizeof(Stack) << endl; // Size of a "std::stack<int>" instance
    cout << "Stack size " << Stack.size() << endl;  // Size (# entries) of stack = 0 (empty)
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No I'm not confused. I know `Stack.size();` will return the stack size.  Because I mentioned I'm trying to understand about memory space.

Comment: @Naiem OK, sorry for assuming your confusion (others *have* made that mistake, though). Maybe my edit gives some hints - although the actual details of the `stack` class will vary between implementations.